# Opencv update to 2.4?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I update OpenCV for ROS? I have read that The ROS Electric currently using 2.3. But I would like to try latest version.

This is duplicated question. Sorry about this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42526/opencv-update-to-2.4?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the related questions there is answer, you should build from source:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9899/how-to-use-very-latest-opencv-version-in-ros/

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/47249/problem-with-using-opencv_gpu-inside-ros/?answer=47303#post-id-47303)

---

Originally posted by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) with karma: 391 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1